# Responsive form label doesnot push content down

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am new to making responsive webpages. I am having trouble in pushing content down when label of a form grows in height. The label of the form doesn't push the orange box down when it grows in length that is at small page width. My code is here:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  #form{
   z-index: 2;
   position:relative;
   width: 35.42%;
   margin-left: 32.71%;
  }

  .column {
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   clear: both;
  }

  #formDiv{
   z-index: 3;
      position: relative;
      margin-right: -10000px;
      width: 100.59%;
      left: 0.3%;
  }

  #label {
      z-index: 4;
      min-height: 28px;
      line-height: 14px;
       text-align: left;
      font-family: Georgia, Palatino, Palatino Linotype, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
      position: relative;
      margin-right: -10000px;
      width: 30%;
  }

  .leftinline{
      display: inline;
      float: left;
  }

  #input {
      z-index: 8;
      min-height: 26px;
      background-color: orange;
      position: relative;
      margin-right: -10000px;
      margin-top: 27px;
      width: 50%;
  } 
 </style>
</head>
<body style="word-wrap:break-word;margin-top:30px;width:100%">
 <form class = "column" id="form" action="/action_page.php">
  <div id="formDiv">
   <label class="leftinline" id="label">
    <span>Nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</span>
   </label>
   <span class="leftinline" id="input"></span>
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me out in this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `label` and `span` are floated they will stack side-by-side as long as there is enough space, so to force a line break, clear the float by adding `clear: left;` to your `.leftinline` rule

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  #form{
   z-index: 2;
   position:relative;
   width: 35.42%;
   margin-left: 32.71%;
  }

  .column {
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   clear: both;
  }

  #formDiv{
   z-index: 3;
      position: relative;
      margin-right: -10000px;
      width: 100.59%;
      left: 0.3%;
  }

  #label {
      z-index: 4;
      min-height: 28px;
      line-height: 14px;
       text-align: left;
      font-family: Georgia, Palatino, Palatino Linotype, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
      position: relative;
      margin-right: -10000px;
      width: 30%;
  }

  .leftinline{
      display: inline;
      float: left;
        clear: left;
  }

  #input {
      z-index: 8;
      min-height: 26px;
      background-color: orange;
      position: relative;
      margin-right: -10000px;
      margin-top: 27px;
      width: 50%;
  } 
 </style>
</head>
<body style="word-wrap:break-word;margin-top:30px;width:100%">
 <form class = "column" id="form" action="/action_page.php">
  <div id="formDiv">
   <label class="leftinline" id="label">
    <span>Nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</span>
   </label>
   <span class="leftinline" id="input"></span>
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! A small explanation on why should I add it will help. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again! But, this seem to add space between textbox and orange box.

Comment: @raju That space is caused by the `margin-top: 27px;` in your `#input` rule